# Is it possible to pause a CAEmitterLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, pause, caemitterlayer

I have a `CAEmitterLayer` instance that emits some `CAEmitterCells`. I'm wondering, is it possible to pause this layer such that no new `CAEmitterCells` are produced and the ones that have been produced remained fixed in their position on the screen? Then, when the `CAEmitterLayer` instance is "un-paused", the fixed `CAEmitterCells` on the screen start to move again.

Thanks for any help here.

**EDIT**

Setting:

```
emitterLayer.speed = 0.1
```

where `emitterLayer` is an instance of a subclass of `CAEmitterLayer`, just **removes the layer completely from the view**.

Setting:

```
emitterLayer.lifetime = 0.0
```

just **stops any new `emitterCells` being produced but doesn't "freeze" the existing `emitterCells` at the current position**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `lifetime` property of the `CAEmitterLayer` to `0`, which will cause newly emitted cells to not even be rendered, but will leave already existing cells unaffected. When you want to "un-pause" your emitter layer, you can simply reset `lifetime` to whatever it was before the pause.

To freeze the existing cells as well, you can set `speed` to `0` and also add a `timeOffset`.

```
extension CAEmitterLayer {
    func pause() {
        // Freeze existing cells
        self.speed = 0
        self.timeOffset = convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: self)
        // Stop creating new cells
        self.lifetime = 0
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call it like `emitterLayer.pause()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `emitterLayer.lifetime = 0` does stop **new** `emitterCells` from being made, but doesn't *freeze* the position of `emitterCells` that are already on the screen ...

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis you're right, check my updated answer, this should take care of existing cells as well

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I can't quite get this to work. Setting `speed` to anything <1 makes the cells jump vertically upwards. Setting `timeOffset` to >0 makes cells move downwards, which counteracts this I guess? However `convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: self) = 173180.467530244
`, which is far too large? Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexJ.R.Lewis did you actually try these exact values that are present in my answer? You shouldn't set `speed` to anything <1, but set it to exactly 0 and `timeOffset` should be exactly as in my answer following the documentation notes: _"/* Additional offset in active local time. i.e. to convert from parent
     * time tp to active local time t: t = (tp - begin) * speed + offset.
     * One use of this is to "pause" a layer by setting `speed' to zero and
     * `offset' to a suitable value. Defaults to 0. */"_

Comment: Yes I tried your exact values, but they just removed the layer from the screen. I then adjusted the `speed` and `timeOffset` to understand what each of them was doing. I'm using Swift 4 targeted to iOS 11.4 by the way.